Django SMTPAuthenticationError when using the same variable name for EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD in .env and settings.py
I am working on a Django project where I use Gmail for email services. I have the following configuration in my .env file:
EMAIL_HOST_USER=gmail@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=password

And in my settings.py, I load these variables as follows:
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')

When I try to send an email through my application, I encounter an SMTPAuthenticationError.
However, when I change the name of the variable in the .env file, it works fine, but the password is no longer masked. How can I fix this while keeping the password masked?

what do you mean by "but the password is no longer masked"?

However, when I change the name of the variable in the .env file, it works fine, what variable?

Use this:
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST")
EMAIL_PORT = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PORT")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USE_TLS")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")


Some explanation of what you think the problem is and why your solution fixes it would help improve this answer.
